# How to patch rsync the correct way

Tags: 20.04, rsync, patch

I want to patch rsync to support [detect-renamed](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync-patches.git;a=blob;f=detect-renamed.diff;h=5ba95b4eb1b5d0f79cd22719d56fdea72590f87f;hb=HEAD) option, but I don't want to download a patch and extract it, I want to use apt (apt-get), how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to patch a package without rebuilding it yourself.  The easiest way to do this is probably to download the Debian package using apt, then build it with dpkg-buildpackage.  To do this, first ensure that you have a line beginning with `deb-src` in your sources.list file.  If you don't, copy the first 'deb' line (which should contain the name of your release), and switch the first word to `deb-src`.

Then, run `sudo apt-get build-dep rsync` and `apt-get source rsync`.  Then, apply the patch to the source tree normally (instructions are given with this patch).  Finally, call `dpkg-buildpackage` from inside the source tree.  Use Gdebi to install the resulting binary package, which will be located in the parent directory of where the source tree was unpacked.  You could also use dpkg to install it, but using Gdebi provides some useful safety checks.

Comment: Hi, below is my current sources.list, can you help me further by showing how to add the rsync source/patches URL? I can't add the full file in the comment

Comment: I explained how to add the source URL.  The patch URL will need to be handled seprately: as far as I know, Apt is not designed to download and apply patches on packages at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.